# Is simultaneous I2C, SPI and USB communication between multiple MSP430s possible?

Tags: usb, communication, i2c, msp430, spi

I have programmed a couple of MSP430x6xx microcontrollers to serve as Master for some I2C slave devices. One of the MSP430s transfer the data received from I2C slaves to a PC using its built in USB Module. I want to extend this to allow all Micro controllers to send data received from their respective I2C slaves to PC using a common bus system. Will it be feasible to use SPI for transferring the data from all MSP430s to a single MSP430 master(already serving as I2C master and USB device simultaneously) which then transfers it to PC? I would appreciate any other suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is feasible we will have to write your firmware to handle this. You have to identify on the PC somehow from whom SPI/I2C slave it comes the data. So, your main MSP430xxx will do this adding some kind of header to the data saying the id of the slave device.